# Linear regression with a variable length list as a feature

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, regression

I am building a regression model in python(`scikit-learn`) to predict time taken(`y`) for a process based on roughly 300 observations. One of 5 features is a integer list of variable length. Both the sum of the list members and length of list are significant predictors of `y` as per initial model. Since I don't have any more data, I want to use the entire list as one of the features. But I can't figure out how to handle the variation in list length.

One way is to use mean, max, dist etc of the list as features.Any better ideas ?

EDIT: `X` is attributes of a workflow batch-processing multiple items and `y` is the time taken to complete that. One of the attributes in `X` is a variable length list like [3,8,1,3000] which records items per category. All categories have similar processing times, but the number of categories matter. So [CategoryX:30] and [CategoryY:30] will run in same time, but [CategoryX:15,CategoryY:15] time will be different from above two, even though number of total items is same.Example data is below where last column is what I'm trying to predict:

```
12, 1234,  timestamp, [1230,23,12,2,8,90],34.78
34, 21345, timestamp, [2,45],45.89
90, 45678, timestamp,[1,5, 89,45],56.78
```

so on.

Comment: Maybe you could give more context: how did you obtain this list, and what is its relationship to Y.

Comment: Could you show some data?!

Comment: @AmiTavory added some sample data.

Comment: @Stormbringer How many different categories do you have and are they constant? If they are constant and not too many you could use them as fixed features and just set them to 0 if not present. As alternative, just use the statistics of the list as features (i.e: length, mean, max, sum, ...)

Comment: @RobinSpiess The number of categories is variable, so I ended up doing something similar to your suggestion, using list statistics as features.

Comment: @Stormbringer Yeah, from your description this seems to be the most sensible approach in that case. Btw, you can always post a self-answer where you describe what you've done in the end.